# Upload ZIP-files with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the following code to upload and extract a ZIP-archive in PHP using CodeIgniter.

```
    $config['upload_path'] = 'backups/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'zip';
    $config['file_name'] = $project_id;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( file_exists('backups/' . $project_id . '.zip') ) {
        try {
            delete_file('backups/' . $project_id . '.zip');
        } catch (exception $e) {
            // do nothing...
        }
    }

    if ( $this->upload->do_upload('zip_archive') ) {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

        $file_name = 'backups/'.$upload_data['file_name'];

        $this->sync_model->extract_zip_archive($project_id, $file_name, TRUE);

        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>','</p>');
    }
```

I get the error though "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed." even though it is a valid .zip file I am uploading. (It's size does not exceed the maximum allowed)

This problem also occurs with every filetype I've tried that's not an image.

Any pointers?
Cheers!

Comment: Sure: 0x3A28213A, 0x6339392C, 0x7363682E. http://xkcd.com/138/

Comment: That was actually funny, but doesn't solve the issue :)

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the code provided by "kofic" here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/113029/

Comment: It would be great if you could provide the solution here rather than the link. I am unable to open the link.

Answer (score 4):

```
$config['allowed_type']
```

Should be a list of mime types, but it just so happens that sometimes just the file extension will work (this is the case with images at least).

Try:

```
$config['allowed_type'] = 'application/zip';
```

Although these are also mime types for zip:

```
application/x-zip
application/x-zip-compressed
application/octet-stream
application/x-compress
application/x-compressed
multipart/x-zip
```

Comment: To be more specific, the only extensions that will work on `$config['allowed_type']` are gif, jpg, jpeg, png, and jpe. As for what CodeIgniter expects you to put in `$config['allowed_type']`, you can check out `system/application/config/mimes.php`.

Comment: Ok, I set the variable like this:
$config['allowed_types'] = 'application/zip|application/x-zip|application/x-zip-compressed|application/octet-stream|application/x-compress|application/x-compressed|multipart/x-zip';

And I recieve: "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your 'allowed_types' as 'zip', but making sure that you extend the mime types that are considered 'zip'.

I changed line 54 of my 'application/config/mimes.php' to:

```
'zip'   =>  array(
    'application/x-zip', 
    'application/zip', 
    'application/x-zip-compressed', 
    'application/octet-stream', 
    'application/x-compress', 
    'application/x-compressed', 
    'multipart/x-zip'),
```

(Credit to Matthew Rapati for the list of MIME types)

The truth is that once you allow 'application/octet-stream', the uploaded file could be pretty much anything so part of the purpose of restricting the allowed types vanishes. But since CI forces you to set it to something, I think it is still better than:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```

Which also works.